# Safari html video controls appearing for one second

Tags: html, safari, html5-video

I have a problem with a website I'm working on. Using the Safari browser, while the page is loading, the video control appear just for a second (like on the image) and then it disappears.

[image]

The main page of the website has a full-screen video but I set the `controls=false` in the attributes. And the main problem is that it always appears, also when there is no video in the page is loading. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 0):

`controls` is a Boolean attribute so its very presence means that it is true, regardless of what you set it to.
Try ommitting it entirely.